# Max value from auto commit false table

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, commit, rollback

My problem is i have set a table auto commit false. I need to get the max id from that table(the currently inserted value of auto increment id). But i am getting the id of the previous committed process. Is it possible to get the value

My real problem is i need to insert into table some values, And need to take the id of the last inserted record from the first table and insert it to the second. The second insertion includes some image upload as well(as part of the code). so it take some delay or can have exceptions. I need to undo all insertions(both in the first and second) by occurring any exceptions. I tried to use commit-roll back method for this. But its not properly working as i mentioned above. main portion of my code is written below

```
try
{

//getting connection and setting auto commit false
dbHandler dbGetConnect=new dbHandler();
Connection conRegPlot=null;
conRegPlot=dbGetConnect.getconn();
conRegPlot.setAutoCommit(false);


String qryInsertPlot="INSERT INTO property_table(name,message,owner,locality,lattitude,longitude,country,state,city,type,catagory,created,modified,creted_date,zoompoint,mob_no,title,img_path,expire_date,lease_term) VALUES('none','"+description+"','"+sessionUserId+"','"+locality+"','"+lattitude+"','"+longitude+"','"+country+"','"+state+"','"+city+"','"+type+"','"+catagory+"',NOW(),NOW(),CURDATE(),'"+zoom+"','"+mob_no+"','"+title+"','NOT IN USE',"+expireDate+",'"+termsAndConditions+"')";//insertion into the first table

Statement stCrs=conRegPlot.createStatement();
int resp=stCrs.executeUpdate(qryInsertPlot);

String qryGetMaxProperty="SELECT MAX(l_id)"+
        " FROM property_table"+
            " WHERE stat='active'"+
            " AND CURDATE()<=expire_date";
propertyId1=dbInsertPropert.returnSingleValue(qryGetMaxProperty);// get the max id


String qryInsertImage="INSERT INTO image_table(plot_id,ownr_id,created_date,created,modified,stat,img_path) VALUES('"+propertyId1+"','"+sessionUserId+"',CURDATE(),NOW(),NOW(),'active','"+img_pth+"')";

            Statement stImg=conRegPlot.createStatement();
            stImg.executeUpdate(qryInsertImage);// inserting the image


conRegPlot.commit();    
}
catch(Exception exc)
{
    conRegPlot.rollback();

}
finally{
    conRegPlot.close();
}
```

Comment: This site should be called *SQL Injection*, not *Stack Overflow*. Does anyone ever escape the stuff they put in their SQL statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

> And need to take the id of the last inserted record from the first
>   table and insert it to the second.

You could the use of the new `JDBC 3.0` method `getGeneratedKeys()` for get the generated ID. In ahother hand, you should use `PreparedStatement` for avoid SQL Injection.

```
 PreparedStatement ps = null;
 try {
    conn = getConnection();
    ps = conn.prepareStatement(myQuery, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    ps.setInt(1, anInteger);
    ...
    int rows = ps.executeUpdate();
    if (rows == 1) {
        ResultSet keysRS = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
        if (keysRS.next())
            int id = keysRS.getInt(1) // Get generated id
```

For MySQL, see more in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-last-insert-id.html#connector-j-examples-autoincrement-getgeneratedkeys

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer it works for me. and i will try to use prepared statement